# My laptop dropped while Linux was on and since then I can’t seem to reboot

Tags: kali-linux

This is what it shows on the screen:

```
Loading Linux 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 ...
error: attempt to read or write outside disk ‘hd0’.
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue ..._
```

And then it returns to GNU GRUB version2.02~beta3-5

[image]

Comment: But my windows still loads because it dual booted. When I made a bootable disk using Rufus I could access my files on both partictions both the Linux and windows please any help

Comment: Consider a cup. Now drop it. Ooops, the handle's snapped off. It's still a cup and can hold liquid. But it's broken and if you try to use the handle you can't. Furthermore, the cup might be microscopically cracked and sooner or later it will snap into pieces. That's your disk drive.

Comment: Thanks so there is no way to make the Linux boot back normally

Comment: It's not Linux. It's your disk drive.

Answer (score 5):

You've broken the laptop. If you're lucky it's just the disk drive, and they're relatively easy to replace.

You can check the disk drive with a Rescue CD, and run `smartctl -a /dev/sda`. Post the results (as text) in your question and someone can interpret for you.